# How Can I Find Peak Values of Defined Areas from Spectrogram Data using numpy?

Tags: numpy, scipy, reduction, spectrogram

I have spectrogram data from an audio analysis which looks like this:

[image]

On one axis I have frequencies in Hz and in the other times in seconds. I added the grid over the map to show the actual data points. Due to the nature of the used frequency analysis, the best results never give evenly spaced time and frequency values.

To allow comparison data from multiple sources, I would like to normalize this data. For this reason, I would like to calculate the peak values (maximum and minimum values) for specified *areas* in the map.

[image]

The second visualization shows the areas where I would like to calculate the peak values. I marked an area with a green rectangle to visualize this.

While for the time values, I would like to use equally spaced ranges (e.g 0.0-10.0, 10.0-20.0, 20.0-30.0), The frequency ranges are unevenly distributed. In higher frequencies, they will be like 450-550, 550-1500, 1500-2500, ...

You can download an example data-set here: [data.zip](https://luckyresistor.me/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/data.zip). You can unpack the datasets like this:

```py
    with np.load(DATA_PATH) as data:
        frequency_labels = data['frequency_labels']
        time_labels = data['time_labels']
        spectrogram_data = data['data']
```

`DATA_PATH` has to point to the path of the `.npz` data file.

As input, I would provide an array of frequency and time ranges. The result should be another 2d NumPy `ndarray` with either the maximum or the minimum values. As the amount of data is huge, I would like to rely on NumPy as much as possible to speed up the calculations.

**How do I calculate the maximum/minimum values of defined areas from a 2d data map?**

Comment: what do the different colours represent?

Comment: The colors are sound pressure levels in dB(V). Simple floating-point values in a given range.